# Firefox Debugging, open localhost from desktop PC on smartphone

Tags: debugging

Good day,

a page hosted on localhost should be accessible with a smartphone. At least there is already a connection through which pages can be called up on the smartphone and inspected on the desktop PC.

If you call localhost on your smartphone you get "Error: Connection failed". Something has to be adjusted to make it work. How can connect to localhost?

With the IP (127.0.0.1) there is the same error message. Is it maybe a different IP? Or port forwarding, or port forwarding reverse? I can't find enough information about this in my language, but a connection already exists, shouldn't be missing a lot.

Comment: For IPv4, localhost usually refers to 127.0.0.1. If you have a webserver running on the PC then you will need to configure it so that it is available on the LAN with some other suitable IP address, and the phone needs to be able to connect to it - you would use the IP address, not "localhost". [Wikipedia: localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The network profile had to be switched to private. The IPv4 address of the desktop PC then led directly to the "Index of localhost". Thanks for the solutions, it finally works.